# Mysql query to get main product and variables

Tags: mysql

I'm dealing with this situation:

```
  ID   | PostParent  | PostType
----------------------------------------------
 001   |  NULL       | 'product'
 002   |  001        | 'product_variation'
 003   |  001        | 'product_variation'
 004   |  NULL       | 'product'
 005   |  004        | 'product_variation'
 006   |  004        | 'product_variation'
```

I need to implement a query that for a given ID outputs the

```
  ID   | PostParent  | PostType            
-------------------------------------------
 001   |  NULL       | 'product'
 002   |  001        | 'product_variation'
 003   |  001        | 'product_variation'
```

The purpose is to output in the single product page, the product info and the list of its variations if they exist.

Comment: I implemented the following one --->SELECT

p.id,
p.post_parent,
p.post_type

FROM mg_posts as p

WHERE p.post_parent= p.id     <---- but it gives any results

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at your expected output.

Comment: Why are 005 and 006 excluded from the results?

Comment: Just to explain that I need to query one product per time. 004, 005 and 006 are a separated group

Comment: Tim, I am on the wrong way I understand from your comment

Comment: Define the rule that separates '5' into the '4' group

Comment: @Tim, I need to display in a single php page the product (with its attributes) and in a list, the variations associated to the main product.

Comment: Sorry guy I made a mistyping error. Records 005 and 006 are linked to 004. I updated the initial post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a union all

```
  select ID, PostParent, PostType
  from mg_posts
  where ID = '001'
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT id, PostParent, PostType 
  FROM mg_posts  
  WHERE p.post_parent=  '001'
```

Comment: Ok I am going to test it

Comment: It definitively gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your explanation is somewhat poor, and if you accept this answer great, but please reword your question, but I think you are asking for this:

```
SELECT mg1.*, mg2.* FROM mg_posts mg1 LEFT JOIN mg_posts mg2 ON mg2.PostParent = mg1.ID
```

That is the implicit relationship of the table.  If you were looking for product ID = 1, then you'd further refine your query:

```
SELECT mg1.*, mg2.* FROM mg_posts mg1 LEFT JOIN mg_posts mg2 ON mg2.PostParent = mg1.ID WHERE mg1.ID = 1; -- the one I know to get
```

The `LEFT JOIN` assures that you'd get products even if they don't have product variations.  Make sense?  You'd use `JOIN` if you wanted products only with variations, or only if you were 110% sure all products have variations upon entry (and I do mean 110%).

If you want to list everything on one row as you did, you'd do this:

```
SELECT * FROM mg_posts WHERE (ID = 1 AND PostParent IS NULL) OR PostParent = 1
```

Hope that helps, but update your post :)

Comment: Oliver, I implemented my original post, in the final part